# Jackson deserialise JsonPatch with object value

Tags: java, json, spring, json-patch

I'mu using JsonPatch (JSR-374) with implementation from Apache org.apache.johnzon:johnzon-core:1.2.4 in my Spring project PATCH endpoint:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JSR353Module());
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Controller

```
@PatchMapping("/settings")
public ResponseEntity<SettingsResponse> patchSettings(@RequestBody JsonPatch patchDocument, Locale locale) {...}
```

With json request of a simple atomic values

```
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/currency", "value": "EUR" },
  { "op": "test", "path": "/version", "value": 10 }
]
```

JsonPatch instance is deserialised correctly by Jackson

But with complex value type (object):

```
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/currency", "value": {"code": "USD", "label": "US Dollar"} },
  { "op": "test", "path": "/version", "value": 10 }
]
```

Exception is thrown

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `javax.json.JsonPatch` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

I recon JsonPatch (and its Apache JsonPatchImpl) is capable of working with complex types as JsonValue mentions JsonObject and ValueType.OBJECT, but I don't know how to instruct Jackson to deserialise correctly

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

Comment: Class `JsonPatch` doesn't have constructor with no parameters. So Spring can't create an instance of it. Consider to use other class with following copying of data.

Comment: JsonPatch is the interface. I guess you mean it Apache imp. JsonPatchImpl. Maybe other JSR-374 implementation has no difficulties with deserialising complex types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through this by using the JSR-364 Implementation Json.createPatch:

```
@PatchMapping("/settings")
public ResponseEntity<SettingsResponse> patchDefaultSettingsJsonP3(@RequestBody String patchString, Locale locale) {
    try (JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(patchString))) {
        JsonPatch patch = Json.createPatch(jsonReader.readArray());
        ...
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I found wiser solution by registering the converter as a bean. Spring then takes care of the deserialisation internally

```
@Component
public class JsonPatchHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<JsonPatch> {

public JsonPatchHttpMessageConverter() {
    super(MediaType.valueOf("application/json-patch+json"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}

@Override
protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return JsonPatch.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

@Override
protected JsonPatch readInternal(Class<? extends JsonPatch> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(inputMessage.getBody())) {
        return Json.createPatch(reader.readArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException(e.getMessage(), inputMessage);
    }
}

@Override
protected void writeInternal(JsonPatch jsonPatch, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    throw new NotImplementedException("The write Json patch is not implemented");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the mentioned above by [Tomáš Mika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4113073/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-mika) I would add my comment / use-case.

**Pre-conditions**

- `Spring-Boot` + `Lombok` + `Jackson` + `JsonPatch` usage
- `JsonPatchHttpMessageConverter` - as defined [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61181616/8956733)

At some point after colleagues `cleanup` commit all `PATCH` APIs have stopped working, by throwing the `InvalidDefinitionException` with error message:

```
Cannot construct instance of `javax.json.JsonValue` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
```

After some time & investigation it was found that:

- Exception has thrown by `ObjectMapper` deserializer, specifically in method:

  `protected Object _convert(Object fromValue, JavaType toValueType)`

*line **#4388***:

```
result = deser.deserialize(p, ctxt);
```

The reason was missing `ObjectMapper` bean, previously created to enable `JsonPatch` and lately removed by mistake in scope of some `cleanup`:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .findAndRegisterModules();
}
```

This `ObjectMapper` bean has been explicitly defined, in addition to the extensive configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Value("${spring.jackson.date-format:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")
private String dateFormatPattern;

@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.forEach(converter -> {
        if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = jacksonConverter.getObjectMapper();
            jacksonConverter.setPrettyPrint(true);
            configureObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        }
    });
}

private void configureObjectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern));

    // https://programming.vip/docs/61b9674a30f8c.html
    mapper.setVisibility(
            mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                    .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                    .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                    .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                    .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    );

    // Serializers
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    mapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNWRAPPED_TYPE_IDENTIFIERS);

    // Deserializers
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNRESOLVED_OBJECT_IDS);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);

    mapper.registerModule(hibernate5Module());
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
}

    @Bean
public Module hibernate5Module() {
    Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();
    hibernate5Module.enable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.REPLACE_PERSISTENT_COLLECTIONS);
    return hibernate5Module;
  }
}
```